# Responsive web pages - designing for height

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, raphael

My apologies in advance if this question sounds more like looking for opinions or discussion.

I'm designing a game-type page using the Raphael library instead of Canvas. My first design decision was the use percentages for everything, so that it may utilize all or most of the available screen, regardless of the resolution being used (which, now, I know maybe be damn near impossible to achieve).

When I read about responsive design, I always hear about designing for the width, which really makes sense because the content can be browsed up and down. But, what about designing with the height in mind? What if I want all the information needed in this game to be accessible with no vertical scrolling?

What's the standard practice here? Is it the media-query route with pre-defined element dimensions and designing for the most popular resolutions? Or, is it actually possible to create a complex system with sizes as percentages?

Man, this really sounds opinion-based but I'm hoping there's a guide or article discussing this topic out there that I've missed.

Comment: You can always use JS to get height of the users window, and size your container div appropriately while setting overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use percentages if you're using a library that manipulates SVG (which it appears Raphael does). Instead, you can set the size of the SVG "canvas" element to whatever size you want.

To get your game to fill up 100% of that space, you can put all graphics into a [`g` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g), get the size of the SVG element (if it wasn't known) using Raphael (or jQuery or similar if Raphael can't for some reason), then [scale/translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) that g element based on that height so it fills the screen.

That way, you do not need to think in percentages!

Comment: Of course, damn. Why didn't I think of that? :p Walk through this with me... I get a base layout together- say, 800x600 (not accounting for mobile yet). Then, I can get the height of the div that contains the paper (Raphael's implementation of canvas). To keep the aspect ratio correct, I find how much the height has changed compared to 600px and apply it to the width? As far as I know, Raphael doesn't have functionality to fit elements into anything.

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right, except if you're using svg, you'd use `scale` inside of the `transform` attribute. You would just find the correct scale factor that would get your 800x600 fitting into whatever sized box you actually have. If your container were actually 400x400, then you would have to scale by 0.5, giving 400x300 (leaving 50 pixels top and bottom unused).